# Deleting Files within Subdirectories using Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

Here is the script that I am currently working with:

```
forfiles -p E:\datatel\coll18\developmentSQL\apphome\_HOLD_\ -s -m * /D -28 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

The -s should allow me to delete files within the sub-directories without removing the folders, but instead I receive a "No files found" error.  Am I overlooking something simple?  I've tried switching the - to a / for continuity, but the results are the same.

Comment: Probably because there isn't any file that is modified within last 28 days. Your code works okay when I tried it. Also, since -m * is a default option, you can take it out if you want.

Comment: @ThomasWeller `@file` only gives you the name of the file while `@path` gives you the full path of the file.

Comment: The command line looks fine to me. Are you sure there are still files after the command has run?